# Embedding in Keras

Tags: keras, nlp, data-science, word-embedding

Which algorithm is used for embedding in Keras built-in function?
Word2vec? Glove? Other?

https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is **neither**. In essence, an embedding layer such as *Word2Vec* of *GloVe* is just a small neural network module (fully-connected layer usually) that projects higher, sparse dimensionality into a lower, n-dimensional vector.

When you insert a *fresh* random embedding layer in Keras into your neural network, Keras will construct a dense learnable matrix of shape `[input_dim, output_dim]`.

Concretely, let's say that you're inserting an Embedding layer to encode *integer scalar* month information (12 unique values) into a *float vector* of size 3. In Keras, you're going to declare your embedding as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Embedding, Input
x = Input(shape=(1000,)) # suppose seq_len=1000
embedding = Embedding(12+1, 3, input_length=1000)(x)
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs= embedding) # Functional API
model.summary()
```

Your embedding layer would have a summary as follows:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 1000)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 1000, 3)           39        
=================================================================
Total params: 39
Trainable params: 39
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Notice that the learnable parameters are `39 = 13*3` (the +1 is needed by Keras to encode values that don't belong to any of the 12 unique months - *just in case*).

Also notice that while the input shape to embedding is shaped `(None, 1000)`, the output of the embedding is shaped `(None, 1000, 3)`. This means the very small dense weight matrix of size `[13, 3]` is applied to **each** of the 1000 input time-steps. Which means, every month integer input of `0-11` will be converted into a float vector of size `(3,)`.

This also means that when you do backpropagation from the final layer into the embedding layer, the gradient to *each* of the 1000 time-steps embedding output will also flow (in a `time_distributed` manner) to the small neural network weights (which is, *essentially*, the **embedding** layer) of size `[13,3]`.

Please also refer to official Keras documentation for Embedding layer: https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/.

Comment: GloVe is not a neural network, it is setup as a linear least-squares regression problem.

Answer (score 3):

None of the above. It is by default initialised randomly `embeddings_initializer='uniform'`.

There is a [tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html) on how to use existing embeddings.

Comment: so this embedding has no meaning at all?

Comment: yes, it will be uniformly random values by default.

Comment: embedding has no mean at all, does it means it useless?